# Get search bar in navigation bar in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

So I've tried everything trying to get a search bar into the navigation bar in Swift. But sadly I haven't gotten it working, just yet...

For those of you who don't know what I'm talking about, I'm trying to do something like this

[image]

Note the search bar in the navigation bar. So here's what I'm currently using

```
self.searchDisplayController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
```

I popped that in my `viewDidLoad`, and then when I load up the app I'm presented with, just an empty navigation bar.... :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this

```
let leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:Yoursearchbar)
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

**Update**

You keep a lazy UISearchBar property

```
lazy   var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
```

In viewDidLoad

```
searchBar.placeholder = "Your placeholder"
var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchBar)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

If you want to use storyboard
just drag your searchbar as a outlet,then replace the lazy property with your outlet searchbar

Comment: How would I identify `Yoursearchbar`?

Comment: So far so good. But how would I add a placeholder? Any way through storyboards?

Comment: You just change the property of searchbar to add a placeholder.I update the answer

Comment: Hi, can you show me the whole code for this? I don't really understand about `lazy` part

Comment: Can some one please tell me how to add the `lazy` part as mentioned in the end of the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone explain what does lazy do? What's the difference between lazy var searchBar vs var searchBar

Comment: This is not working for me, no searchBar is displayed when i try this code line for line

Comment: Swift 3 CGRectMake is now CGRect. lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height:200))

Comment: Don't put searchBar into leftBarButtonItem. Creates all types of problems. Follow the suggest given below by antonio081014

Comment: @Leo,   bro could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375778/add-navigation-bar-in-uicollectionview-in-swift-4-ios-11  ?

Answer (score 65):

```
    // create the search bar programatically since you won't be
    // able to drag one onto the navigation bar
    searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.sizeToFit()

    // the UIViewController comes with a navigationItem property
    // this will automatically be initialized for you if when the
    // view controller is added to a navigation controller's stack
    // you just need to set the titleView to be the search bar
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Comment: That is a much better way than any other solutions.

Comment: @antonio081014, bro could you help me to take a look at my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375778/add-navigation-bar-in-uicollectionview-in-swift-4-ios-11   ?

Answer (score 33):

Swift 5, XCode 11, Storyboard way so you can easily add all the search bar attributes through the **storyboard** and you have **less code** in your view controller class.

**1.) Add your search bar view as external view in viewcontroller.**

[image]

**2.) Connect searchBarView to you viewcontroller.**

[image]

**3.) Add your searchBarView to your navigationBar title item.**

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more. I had no idea you could do this!!

Comment: @Egzon This one is changing size of navigation bar from 44 to 56. So when i am going back to previous view controller, getting blink of navigation controller updating to its original size 44. Any suggestion on it please.

Comment: Hi @MiteshDobareeya, I will check on the next week what's the issue and get back to you. Are you pushing the view controller in the same UINavigationViewController?

Comment: @EgzonP. Yes, I am pushing it into the same UINavigationViewController. Main Root view controller navigation bar has a perfect size 44. And when I push second view controller and adding search bar, then size of navigation bar into second vc gets increased to 56. So when I am pop to first vc then its navigation bar gets a blink.

Answer (score 25):

In your view controller:

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"

    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

Doing it this way, by setting the navigationItem.titleView, the search bar is automatically centered across the iPhone and iPad devices. Note: only tested with v8.4 and v9.0

**for SWIFT 3**

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Comment: How to remove it from navigationItem.titleView when user taps "cancel" button?

Comment: Same question ^

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you're speaking of the search bar cancel button. Implement the UISearchBarDelegate function, searchBarCancelButtonClicked(:), calling navigationItem.titleView = nil in that function. This should remove the search bar if that's what you meant by "remove it". For normal search bar functionality, also ensure you implement searchBarSearchButtonClicked(:) adding searchBar.resignFirstResponder() to remove keyboard when search button is clicked (or started via return key press)

Comment: Updated code for Swift 3:
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)

Answer (score 23):

In 2019, you should use UISearchController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self.viewModel
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search artists"
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

And some class should conform to UISearchResultsUpdating. I usually add this as extension to my ViewModel.

```
extension ArtistSearchViewModel: UISearchResultsUpdating {

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print("Searching with: " + (searchController.searchBar.text ?? ""))
    let searchText = (searchController.searchBar.text ?? "")
    self.currentSearchText = searchText
    search()
    }
}
```

This will spawn something like this:

[image: search bar]

Comment: This solution works fine but I have an issue when my tableView has only a few rows and the height is apparently not enough. When I scroll down the searchbar disappears and then I can't get it back by scrolling up again since it doesn't need to scroll to show all rows. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @JDK Sadly, I do not know for sure. :( You can try observing Pull to Refresh and when it is triggered, you can try to manually tell UISearchBar to show. I am just throwing an idea.

Comment: @JDK92 I know its a late answer but if you want the search bar sticky always you can use this navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

Answer (score 11):

### For iOS 11 and above

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

[image]

### For iOS 10 and below

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
```

[image]

or you can assign it as leftBarButtonItem as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26726605/1599713)

Answer (score 3):

***For Swift 5 or letter***

also, you can use this code. **Fully Programmatically**

```
import UIKit

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    sc.searchResultsUpdater = self
    sc.delegate = self
    sc.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    sc.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter A Compiny Name Or Symbole"
    sc.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
    return sc
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNavigationBar()
}

   private func setupNavigationBar() {
       navigationItem.searchController = searchController
   }

 }

// MARK: - UISearchResult Updating and UISearchControllerDelegate  Extension
  extension SearchTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    
    }
 }
```

[image: After Clicking Search]

[image: After Clicking Cancel Button In Search]

Answer (score 2):

```
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = ""
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = searchBar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.text = nil
    print("## search btn clicked : \(searchBar.text ?? "")")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Setting SearchBar as titleView, changes height of navigationBar to 56. To fix this, you can embed searchBar in view and set that as titleView.

```
    var offset: CGFloat = 20

    // If VC is pushed, back button should be visible
    if navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem != nil {
        offset = 40
    }

    let customFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width - offset, height: 44.0)
    let searchBarContainer = UIView(frame: customFrame)
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: customFrame)
    searchBarContainer.addSubview(searchBar)
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBarContainer
```

Comment: the solution is soso because you could have rightBarButtonItems and frame is not appropriate in that case