# Show Navigation Bar in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm creating an App in swift. My first viewController (Login) shows perfectly with the action bar. But in others view controller i can't see the navigation bar. I was trying to embed all over controller in the navigationController,but it does not work. For example,i have other view controller with the name showlistas that have a search bar, when it loads, i see only the search bar, the navigation bar does;t appear. How can i solve it please?

Comment: How do you create the search bar?  [Is it like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26726605/2521004)?

Comment: I drag the search from the control panel, and i put it in the navigation bar, and automatically it fills all the content of my navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try making all the segues 'push' segues, it seems to make a difference to me.

Comment: it works perfectly for all other viewcontrollers, but i have a controller that contains a google map, when i use 'push' segues it doesn't show me the map. How can i when i resolve it? please help

Comment: So there is a segue between the navigation controller and the controller which doesn't show the nav bar, and the segue is a push segue? Can you please clarify what the embed segue is?